# Font awesome icons toggles twice on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am using font awesome icon for play and pause button. but icons are toggling twice on click. could any one help me with this.

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="iconChange">
        <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    </a>
</div>

$('#iconChange').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
});
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/Ly9jdd1m/

Comment: since you have a pause and a play button, they are probably both using `<i class="fa fa-play"></i>` which is causing it to call twice.  You may need to include a different id for each.

Comment: There is no problem with the code.  Do you have some other code affecting this icon?

Comment: Pass the event `e` as argument and add `e.prevent default` to the click function? Anchor tag has an event listener w/default behavior, and you're adding a 2nd one.